# Optimizing a simple linear curve (constant and coefficient estimated from a regression)

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to calculate the turning point of a a few functions where I have estimated the coefficient and constant from a regression. I'm using the optimize function for this as my curves are all linear.

```
My function looks like:
F<- function(x){
   beta* x + alpha
}
```

mind: beta and alpha are both vectors here. When running the optimisation with optimize, I'm getting the following error:

```
 Error in optimize(F, interval = c(10, 20), lower = (10),  : 
      invalid function value in 'optimize'
```

Is this because optimize is running the optimisation mathematically, so the beta and alphas need to be single parameters? If anyone knows a better way of doing this please do contribute!

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions are linear, then they will be at a minimum at the lower end of the range where beta>=0, and at the upper end of the range if beta<=0 - no need to use `optimize()`.

It's not entirely clear what you're expecting the code to do - if you want it to return an `x` for each set of parameters, look at `optim()` instead and have F return the sum, or run optimize on each set of parameters in turn using an `apply()` function or loop.

One other thing is that your syntax is a bit wonky - I imagine that you mean:

```
> F<- function(x){
+     beta* x + alpha
+ }
> alpha <- 1
> beta <- 2
> optimize(F,c(10,20))
$minimum
[1] 10.00006

$objective
[1] 21.00011
```

Comment: I think the problem is that he named his function `F(x)`, and that is just not a correct way of naming it. The function name should be `Fx` or `F`.

Comment: Sorry! I wrote the F(x) out here just to imply it's a function, I've named it something else for myself. I've edited the OP now to make sure there isn't  confusion.
For simplicity and to focus on the issue with the syntax of optimize, I used an example of linear curves (they will be parabolas later on, but I imagine this won't make a difference in how I write the code so your answers suffice :))
One more question, what is $Objective referring to here? I've tried googling it with no success!
Thank you for your help Miff

Comment: @LCM, the output is composed of those things: `$minimum` (or `$maximum`) and `$objective` which give the location of the minimum (or maximum) and the value of the function at that point, respectively. Basically, `F(minimum or maximum) = $objective`.